# Unknown image header, what could be causing distortions

Tags: image, header, dicom, distortion

I am working on decoding an image file derived from an x-ray machine which is of unknown format.

The extension is **.img**, however this does not match any known formats of this extension, nor does the **magic number heading** match any references I've been able to find online (including DICOM specifications).

The data appears to be uncompressed, so I am able to attain an image by simply parsing the bytes after chopping off a randomly sized header (example images are chopped by ~512 bytes).

Here is the funny part - there appear to be two images embedded in every file, neither of which appears to be rendered correctly, as seen below:

http://ogaard.no/out.jpg

And the original:

http://ogaard.no/in.img

I have little experience with image encoding, and after bedding with Google for a couple of days on the subject I have to give in to the greater forces available on the interwebs - hopefully you.

Does anyone know what this kind of distortion indicates or knows about tools for decomposing/analysing image headers/data structure?

Comment: I think it would help if you could provide the actual .img file with all its headers instead of a JPEG rendering

Comment: *face/palm* I must be getting tired. Edited thanks to @squeamishossifrage 's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what the file format is, but the data appears to consist of signed little-endian 16-bit integers.

This is what I got after stripping the first 2562 bytes:
[image: recovered x-ray images]

The white snow appearing below the X-rays is caused by negative values wrapping round to +255

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton! At least now I can get the images properly rendered - having two per file must just be some kind of bonus (-;

Comment: The two images seem to contain different data, so perhaps these are images produced by some sort of dual-energy equipment. It might be worth trying to combine these images to see if it helps with the extraction of features. More information here: http://www.upstate.edu/radiology/education/rsna/radiography/dual/

Comment: Indeed, the second is used for soft tissue analysis. If you don't mind me asking, @squeamishossifrage, what tools did you use for figuring out data structure/producing the image? Anything more efficient than ImageMagick and standard hex?

Comment: I opened the file in GraphicConverter, which will allow you to open unknown files as raw data where you can specify the image dimensions, colour depth and so on. You'll need OS X to run it though. ImageMagick works well too. Try this: `convert -endian LSB -depth 16 -size 512x1024+2562 gray:in.img -normalize -compress lzw in.tif`

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. I actually had equivalent images, but because of the low brightness I got put off track (which I'm compensating by doing an "-evaluate Multiply 16" now).